# Lenovo 3 and setting up wi-fi offline Fedora version 22

Tags: networking, fedora

Can't seem to get the Wi-Fi to work.

```
$ lspci | grep -i broadcom
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

$ uname -r
4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64
```

I also do not have access to Ethernet on the laptop since there is no wired Ethernet port. I do have access to a desktop with Internet, though.

How can I install packages / set up wi-fi?

Comment: You need to add more info about your system, e.g. what version fedora? You may also find an answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/590442/how-can-i-install-broadcom-wireless-adapter-bcm4352-802-11ac-pcid-14e443b1-r even though that's about Ubuntu; hardware issues such as this are tied to the kernel which is pretty much the same across distributions. It looks like you just don't have the correct driver and/or firmware. Check the output of `dmesg` for relevant lines and include that in your question.

Comment: Fedora 22 and yes i'm almost positive that I'm missing some type of driver but without access to the internet on this laptop I can't simply install the driver through the command line. I was hoping to get a link to the driver needed and then be told how I could manually install it after downloading it from another computer.

Comment: can you run `lspci -nn`, please, to get the pci number rather than just the name? That'll  make it easier to check.

Comment: PCI Number: 14e4:43b1

Comment: See https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/72845/dell-xps-13-no-network-interfaces-after-clean-install-of-f22/